# Dynamically concatenating sequences with Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, observable, rx.net

I want to create a sequence that concatenates one or more sequences created dynamically (in run time).

I tried with `mySequence = mySequence.Concat(anotherSequence)`, but this breaks current subscriptions to `mySequence` since a new sequence is created each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you concatenate one observable sequence to another the first sequence must end before you get any values from the second sequence. It sounds more like you want to merge two or more sequences - in other words, get values from any sequence as soon as that sequence produces the values.

So, if you allow me to change `.Concat` to `.Merge` it sounds like you have code like this at the moment:

```
IObservable<long> mySequence = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)).Take(5);
IDisposable mySequenceSubscription = mySequence.Subscribe(n => Console.WriteLine(n));
IObservable<long> anotherSequence = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2)).Take(5);
mySequence = mySequence.Merge(anotherSequence);
```

If I run that I get these values:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

The second sequence is not merged.

Now, if you don't know at the time that you create the subscription what the future observables you want to merge in are, then you can do this:

```
Subject<IObservable<long>> sources = new Subject<System.IObservable<long>>();
IDisposable sourceSubscription = sources.Merge().Subscribe(n => Console.WriteLine(n));

sources.OnNext(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)).Take(5));
sources.OnNext(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2)).Take(5));
```

Now the results look like this:

```
0
1
0
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
```

This has correctly merged together the two observables that were added **after** the subscription was made. Simple.

Comment: What if you wanted to remove one of the sources afterwards? Is that possible?

Comment: @EduardoBrites - Yes, just end the source. That's fairly easy using `TakeUntil` or one of the other variants of `Take`.